# Lampholder with Socket but no Ground Wire

Tags: electrical, grounding

I was replacing a ceiling lamp holder with chain with a new unit that has a socket however the metal electrical box has 2 wires (black and white) but no ground wire. I replaced it and it is working fine but when I tested the socket it worked but is said Open Ground since there is no ground wire in the electrical box. Is there an easy way to ground the lamp holder/socket?

Thank you

Comment: Would need to add a ground wire/replace the cable or use metal conduit.

Comment: Please revise to add detail about your wiring and any conduit. It's difficult to answer knowing nothing about your hardware.

Comment: A few pictures always come in handy, the wiring, fixture and box.

Comment: The previous fixture may have been grounded to the box.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here and may get snipped, but let's get real:  How important is grounding on a ceiling fixture? Unless you were on an all metal ladder on wet concrete and changing light bulbs with the power on, there's virtually no chance of a path to ground.  So even if there was a ground fault, there's no path to ground.  I'll probably get snipped for this, but this is just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Snip,snip,snip.   Just kidding but I don't think DIYers (or anyone else) should get the idea that they can decide when grounding is important.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Think OP changed it to a light with an outlet(the test showing open ground).  Depending on use, ground might be more important now.  You are right about grounding a ceiling light, think even most table lamps don't use grounding(maybe newer ones do).

Comment: if it's not reversed i wouldn't lose sleep over it. heck even if it was reversed i wouldn't lose sleep over it, especially with long-lasting LED bulbs...

Comment: @crip659  that's a good point. While they might use polarized plugs, I don't know of any that us grounded cords.   One of the other things that gets me is power adapter/supplies for laptops, nearly all are grounded, yet everything is plastic!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- they're the awkward case of a Class II (double insulated) supply that *also* needs primary earthing (for very good EMI control reasons -- in IEC terms, it's a "functional earth" not a "protective earth")